# Vuetify Switcher I18N translation

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I'm using I18N to translate my pages on my vuetify project.

Now, I have a  and i would like to use a vuetify switcher.

Here is my actual code :

```
<template>
    <div>
    <v-app-bar
      color="#007dbc"
      style="z-index: 1000"
    >
    <v-img
        class="mx-2"
        src="@/assets/dkt_logo.png"
        max-height="40"
        max-width="150"
        contain
      ></v-img>
      <v-toolbar-title style="color: white; font-size: 27px">PCB Sizing</v-toolbar-title>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <select v-model="$i18n.locale">
      <option v-for="(lang, i) in langs" :key="`Lang${i}`" :value="lang">
        {{ lang }}
      </option>
    </select>
      

      <v-btn icon @click="logout" v-if="isLogin">
        <v-icon style="color: white">mdi-logout-variant</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
    name : "AppBar",
    data: () => ({
        langs: ['fr', 'en']
    }),
    methods: {
        logout(){
            this.$router.push('/')
        }
    },
    computed:{
        isLogin(){
            return !['Login'].includes(this.$route.name)
        }
    }
    })
</script>
```

And I would like to use a switcher like this in replacement of my select :

```
<v-switch
      v-model="switch1"
      :label="`Switch 1: ${switch1.toString()}`"
    ></v-switch>
```

Do someone have any idea how to do this ?

Thank you

Antoine

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it using a watcher:

```
<template>
  <v-switch v-model="switch1" label="Switch 1"></v-switch>
</template>

<script>
export default Vue.extend({
  data: () => ({
    switch1: false;
  }),
  watch: {
    switch1(newValue, oldValue) {
      this.$i18n.setLocale(newValue ? 'fr' : 'en');
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm using TypeScript and the switcher does not appears

Comment: oups there was a typo in my code I just fixed that

Comment: I have this error message : Property 'setLocale' does not exist on type 'VueI18n & IVueI18n'.ts(2339)

Comment: Try this `this.$i18n.locale = newValue ? 'fr' : 'en'`

Comment: Not working anyway ... The switch does not displays on my page